# DB2 sql queries alias in where clause

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a way where we could query using aliases

```
SELECT 
   'X' AS AVC
 FROM 
   sysibm.sysdummy1
 WHERE AVC= 'X'
```

I am just looking for a way , I could query for alias column.

I am getting the below error.

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=AVC, 
DRIVER=3.63.75
SQLState:  42703
ErrorCode: -206
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, 
DRIVER=3.63.75
SQLState:  26501
ErrorCode: -514
```

Any input would be helpful !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you can't use alias in where condition because the sql engine eval the query  clause  (FROM, WHERE, SELECT...)   in a specific order and the select clause in evaluated  after the where clause

so at the moment of the where evalution the column alias in not know  by th db engine

You must repeat the code

```
SELECT 'X' AS AVC
FROM  sysibm.sysdummy1
WHERE X' = 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  This is a general rule of SQL.  In practice, you can think of the reason being that the `where` is parsed before the `select`, so the aliases are not known.

The general solution is to use a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT 'X' AS AVC
      FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
     ) t
WHERE AVC = 'X';
```

My preferred solution is to use a lateral join, but I don't think DB2 supports either `APPLY` or `LATERAL`.

Comment: The following equivalent queries work in Db2. `SELECT t.* FROM TABLE (VALUES ('X', 'Y') ) t(AVC, AVC2) WHERE AVC = 'X';` or 
`SELECT t.* FROM LATERAL (VALUES ('X', 'Y') ) t(AVC, AVC2) WHERE AVC = 'X';`

Answer (score 0):

The engine does not know of table or column aliases until it is finished gathering the data. You can use them in `ORDER BY` statement within the same query but that's it. You can however, use a [`Common Table Expression`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_createcte.html) also known as a `CTE`:

```sql
WITH myCTE AS (
SELECT 'X' AS AVC
 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
)
SELECT *
  FROM myCTE
    WHERE AVC= 'X'
```

This is somewhat of a long way to do it but unfortunately that is it.